# Python /Pandas - Change negative trailing sign from a column

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please help me with
1) How can I convert negative trailing sign in the 'value' column and bring it to the front (see table below)
2) Filter out all rows that have 0 in the 'value' column.
3) convert the 'value' column to float.
Thanks in advance

```
Project No |    value    |
+------------+-------------+
| H-10030    | 17713.82    |
| H-10030    | 7000        |
| H-10030    | 6073.31     |
| H-10030    | 2400        |
| H-10030    | 4048.87     |
| H-10030    | 1600        |
| H-00026    | 1000        |
| H-00026    | 2500        |
| H-00026    | 800         |
| H-00026    | 0           |
| H-00026    | 0           |
| H-00029    | 0           |
| H-00029    | 0           |
| H-00029    | 8500        |
| H-00029    | 2000        |
| H-00029    | 0           |
| 0-00874    |  59957.25-  |
| 0-00874    |  377375.00- |
| 0-00947    | 0           |
| 0-00947    | 0           |
| 0-01075    | 0           |
| 0-01075    | 0           |
| 0-01075    | 33337       |
| 0-01075    | 0           |
| 0-01080    | 0           |
| 0-01080    | 0           |
| 0-01080    | 0           |
| 0-01082    | 0           |
+------------+-------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+------------+-------------+
| Project No |    value    |
+------------+-------------+
| H-10030    |    17713.82 |
| H-10030    |        7000 |
| H-10030    |     6073.31 |
| H-10030    |        2400 |
| H-10030    |     4048.87 |
| H-10030    |        1600 |
| H-00026    |        1000 |
| H-00026    |        2500 |
| H-00026    |         800 |
| H-00029    |        8500 |
| H-00029    |        2000 |
| 0-00874    |   -59957.25 |
| 0-00874    |  -377375.00 |
| 0-01075    |       33337 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi. That will only work after i convert the trailing negative sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit ugly, but the following code should solve the problem:

```py
df.loc[df["value"].str.endswith("-"), "value"] = (
    "-" + df.loc[df["value"].str.endswith("-"), "value"].str.strip("- ")
)
```

Comment: It worked but when i try to convert it to float it give me this error                              ValueError: could not convert string to float: '- 11533.50' . See the space after negative sign?

Comment: You also need to remove the space. Edited the answer to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for i in df.iterrows():
   if df.loc[i, "value"].str[-1] == '-':
       df.loc[i, "value"] = '-' + df.loc[i, "value"].str[:-1]
df_new = df[df["value"] != 0]]
df_new.value = df.value.astype(float)
```

Comment: I get this error - 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 0):

We can do with `np.where` with  `endswith`

```
df['New']=pd.to_numeric(np.where(df.value.str.endswith('-'),df.value.str[-1]+df.value.str[:-1],df.value))
df=df[df.New!=0]
df
      Project No       value        New
0    H-10030        17713.82   17713.82
1    H-10030            7000    7000.00
2    H-10030         6073.31    6073.31
3    H-10030            2400    2400.00
4    H-10030         4048.87    4048.87
5    H-10030            1600    1600.00
6    H-00026            1000    1000.00
7    H-00026            2500    2500.00
8    H-00026             800     800.00
13   H-00029            8500    8500.00
14   H-00029            2000    2000.00
16   0-00874       59957.25-  -59957.25
17   0-00874      377375.00- -377375.00
22   0-01075           33337   33337.00
```

Answer (score 0):

@tmrlvi Thankyou.

df.loc[df["value"].str.endswith("-"), "value"] = (
    "-" + df.loc[df["value"].str.endswith("-"), "value"].str.strip("- "))

The above code converts the trailing negative sign at the end to the front but leaves a space so I had to

--remove any space before the value
DF['value'] = DF['value'].str.replace(" ","")

--Change datatype to float
DF['value'] = DF.value.astype(float)

--filter 0 rows
DF = DF[DF["value"] != 0]